# GRANT permission to access to respective creator

Tags: mysql, permissions

Does the following command:

GRANT SELECT
ON EVENT
TO STUDENT;

grant student access to whole EVENT table? If yes, how to only give STUDENT access to EVENT(s) record created by respective STUDENT?

Comment: So you're looking to do row based security?

Comment: I guess it's not that, Will answered me. Thanks though..

Comment: It is that. You don't understand the answer you have accepted, which is a row based security implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: When I wrote the answer (below), I did not notice that your question is a MySQL question. Please understand that my answer is for the MS SQL Server platform. I have never used MySQL (and probably never will) so I'm not sure it the permissions model is the same. None-the-less, my "solution" would work in MySQL as long as MySQL provides functions to return the current "user" to match against the saved user information.

Records are not "objects" that can be granted (or denied or revoked) permissions within the SQL Server security system. Only database objects (i.e. tables, views, stored procedures, functions, etc.) can have permissions modified with the GRANT statement. The only way to control access to records created by a given user is to build the database in such a way as to record the "owner" of the records within the data. You could add a column to the table "creator" or some such name and have the user's login saved in the column (you could also save this data in another table. For example (RecordID, UserID) or something to that affect. Then comes your challenge: how to actually control the access to the records. Well, the only way you're going to do that is to ensure that ALL access to the table is given through the use of stored procedures and, within the stored procedures that access the table, you build the logic that checks the current user against the user that saved the record and decide to allow or deny access. Alternatively, you could control the access through the use of a view (that uses a where clause against the user column and a function that returns the current user) but, me personally, I would go the stored procedure route (because I think that all access should be through SPs to begin with)...